# Package import error

Tags: android

I used code of other project so when i clean this project got error coz package name is of the project which i copied from other project. so how can i solve this error.

This is my code.

```
package com.aip.bizaar.common.view.frag;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.aip.bizaar.R;
import com.aip.bizaar.common.view.activity.MainActivity;
import com.aip.bizaar.vo.ImageVO.ImageInfoVO;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;

public class DisplayImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;

    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    public static DisplayImageFragment newInstance(ImageInfoVO dataVO) {
        DisplayImageFragment fragment = new DisplayImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("image", dataVO);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private ImageInfoVO getImageInfo() {
        try {
            return (ImageInfoVO) getArguments().get("image");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gif, container, false);

        ImageInfoVO infoVO = getImageInfo();

        imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        //mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_spinner);

        Ion.with(this)
        .load(infoVO.getImageUrl())
        .withBitmap()
        .animateLoad(R.anim.abc_fade_in)
        .fitCenter()
        .intoImageView(imageView);

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).toggle();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I am getting error in this line. Ion.with(this) . for ion coz it is from import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion; this project package  and my package name is package com.aip.bizaar how i solved this error.

Comment: Replace this import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion; with this import  com.aip.bizaar.Ion;

Comment: replaced bt still getting error how i import this package without an error.

Comment: Can you write here error message? And do you use Android studio or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse m getting import com.aip.bizaar.Ion cannot be resolved error.

Comment: Also replace this Ion.with(this) with this Ion.with(getActivity())

Comment: I am using eclipse m getting import com.aip.bizaar.Ion cannot be resolved error.

Comment: You should add ion jar file to your project. In eclipse, right click to ion jar file and click Build Path -> Add to Build Path. After then clean project.